# If using multiple entity models in azure, do we need multiple configs with SqlAzureExecutionStrategy?

Tags: entity-framework, azure-sql-database

To deal with spurious interrupts in DB calls in an Azure web role to a SQL Azure database, we use this code:

```
public class ContextConfigurations
    : DbConfiguration
{
    public ContextConfigurations()
    {
        SetExecutionStrategy("System.Data.SqlClient", () => new SqlAzureExecutionStrategy());
    }
}
```

This magically makes DB calls better.

If we are using multiple entity models in different namespaces, do we need to call this once for each model somehow to ensure good DB connections?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue:
two EDMX model in two separate VS projects.
Both of the DbContext classes were decorated with the DbConfiguration attribute.
In both projects the DbConfiguration class was defined, even with different namespaces and different class name I were receiving the error when the second model was loaded.

The solution I got was to move the DbConfiguration class in a separate DLL project and reference the dll in both VS project contanining the EDMX.